# NetSuite Advanced PDF Not Respecting the <br> Tags

Tags: netsuite

I can't seem to get my Advanced PDF to respect the `<br>` tags on a long text field (address) so it prints on multiple lines for an envelope window. I've tried the following work-arounds:

NetSuite Long Text Field Console Elements [F12]  Result:

```
TIM TESTER
<br>
123 MAIN STREET
<br>
CHICAGO, IL 63022
```

Attempts:

#1

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%;">
  <#list result.custentity_long_text_address?split("<br />") as z>
    <tr>
    <td>${z}<br /></td>
    </tr></#list></table>
```

#2

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%;">
  <#list result.custentity_long_text_address?split("<br>") as z>
    <tr>
    <td>${z}<br /></td>
    </tr></#list></table>
```

#3 (without table)

```
${result.custentity_long_text_address?replace("<br>", "<br />")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using block elements: `<div>, <p>` and then use CSS to stack them or inline them as you need

Comment: I think this is slightly outside my wheelhouse. Can you give me a basic example to get me started?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the split is splitting the address accordingly?
Using the tr + br tags you should definitely see a line break there (unless the address didn't split).
Can you try with a hardcoded array?

<#assign address= ['TIM TESTER', '123 MAIN STREET', 'CHICAGO, IL 63022']>